# Problema con la deserialización de una cadena en formato JSON usando Jackson en JAVA

Tags: java, json, jackson

Tengo un problema para deserializar un json usando la libreria Jackson en JAVA. 
Recibo el mensaje en formato JSON sin problema, con el formato adecuado, pero por alguna razón dicho mensaje no es posible transformarlo en un objeto.

Este es el codigo que estoy usando:

```
System.out.println("received message : " + json);
SpsPrueba SpsPrueba = new SpsPrueba();

ObjectMapper mapper=new ObjectMapper();
Object Object=new Object();
try{
    Object=mapper.convertValue(json, SpsPrueba.getClass());
}catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

El Objeto que estoy usando para la deserialización es el siguiente:

```
public class SpsPrueba {
    public String DescripcionMensaje;

    public String getDescripcionMensaje() {
        return DescripcionMensaje;
    }

    public void setDescripcionMensaje(String DescripcionMensaje) {
        this.DescripcionMensaje = DescripcionMensaje;
    }

    public double Latitude;

    public double getLatitud() {
        return Latitude;
    }

    public void setLatitud(double Latitud) {
        this.Latitude = Latitude;
    }

    public double Longitude;

    public double getLongitud() {
        return Longitude;
    }

    public void setLongitud(double Longitud) {
        this.Longitude = Longitude;
    }
}
```

Y este es el resultado:

> received message :
>   {"DescripcionMensaje":"Data Track sistema HORUS","Latitude":0.0,"Longitude":0.0}
>
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   Can not construct instance of mil.fac.hansel.pro.DTOS.SpsPrueba:
>   no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value
>   ('{"DescripcionMensaje":"Data Track sistema HORUS","Latitude":0.0,"Longitude":0.0}')

Como pueden ver, el objeto contiene las variables necesarias para almacenar la informacion recibida en el json.

Agradecería cualquier ayuda. Gracias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creo que lo que necesitas es lo siguiente:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
SpsPrueba sps = mapper.readValue(json, SpsPrueba.class);
```

También yo modificaría:

`public class SpsPrueba {`

Por:

`public class SpsPrueba implements Serializable {`

Además de eso algo muy importante es que en tu código no es bueno que tengas definidos los atributos con letras mayúsculas al inicio.

```
private double latitud
private double longitud
```

Comment: Muchas gracias. Funciona de maravilla.